# Apache Camel & Jetty

Tags: apache, localhost, jetty

I want to save the content from a localhost({
   `enter code here`

```
"id": 1,
    "prename": "Noel",
    "surname": "Reyes",
    "dateOfBirth": "1988-09-07",
    "birthPlace": "Bad Ems",
    "gender": "M"}
```

) in a txt.file. 
But:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
      from("jetty:http://localhost:8091/customers/")
              .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
              .convertBodyTo(String.class)
               .log("Test3 ${body}")
              .to("file:dest")
                .end();
```

My route1 started and is consuming from localhost but it does not save it in the text.file.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route does not consume from the localhost. Actually, you are using jetty as a consumer (**from**), that means that you provides the endpoint so you can later on call it from a browser.

I think you want to create a producer (**to**), to call the service. This can be done via camel-http4 component.

Thus, you need a route the starts let's say via a timer (every 5 secs), and the you need to call your endpoint:

```
from("timer://foo?period=5s")
  .to("http4://localhost:8091/customers/")
  .log("Test3 ${body}")
  .to("file:dest");
```

Comment: Dear Themis Pyrgiotis,

I hereby want to thank you very much, this solved my problem.

But we will get back to you if we have further interest in solving problems regarding Apache Camel.

Kindest Regards,
    @JDog